# How to get specific values in attributes via Twilio go SDK?

Tags: go, twilio, twilio-api

Why is the definition of the `TrusthubV1EndUser` structure in the official go SDK so complex and how do I get the values in the specific `Attributes`?

There is also no official single test file provided that I can refer to.

```golang
// TrusthubV1EndUser struct for TrusthubV1EndUser
type TrusthubV1EndUser struct {
    // The SID of the Account that created the resource
    AccountSid *string `json:"account_sid,omitempty"`
    // The set of parameters that compose the End Users resource
    Attributes *interface{} `json:"attributes,omitempty"`
    // The ISO 8601 date and time in GMT when the resource was created
    DateCreated *time.Time `json:"date_created,omitempty"`
    // The ISO 8601 date and time in GMT when the resource was last updated
    DateUpdated *time.Time `json:"date_updated,omitempty"`
    // The string that you assigned to describe the resource
    FriendlyName *string `json:"friendly_name,omitempty"`
    // The unique string that identifies the resource
    Sid *string `json:"sid,omitempty"`
    // The type of end user of the Bundle resource
    Type *string `json:"type,omitempty"`
    // The absolute URL of the End User resource
    Url *string `json:"url,omitempty"`
}
```

Github link:https://github.com/twilio/twilio-go/blob/v0.26.0/rest/trusthub/v1/model_trusthub_v1_end_user.go#L23

Comment: I have never seen such a bad SDK, and the official SDK doesn't allow raising issues directly on github